# Android create bitmap from drawingcache for view bigger than screen

Tags: android, android-bitmap, drawingcache

I am using `Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getDrawingCache());` for creating image from my view so I can than share it. It works perfectly but when mView is bigger then the phone screen I get a null pointer exeption:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I didn't find any way to get around this error so I created an image in a different way(by drawing on canvas):

```
int w = mView.getWidth();
int h = mView.getHeight();
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h,  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
mView.draw(canvas);
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.